# Chart.js | How to update zoomed graph datapoints if dataset is is shifted in x axis?

Tags: chart.js

I use chart.js together with the crosshair plugin.

I have the following problem:
I have 2 wattage graphs from fit files in 1 canvas.
Sometimes the recordings are slightly time shifted, so I implemented the possibility to shift the x axis timestamps to be able to move the graphs to match them.

The shifting is implemented through manipulation of actual data (the timestamps are epoch in milliseconds):

```
 data.map((element) => {
        element["x"] =  element["x"] - 1000
        return element["x"]["y"];
      });
chart.update();
```

The shifting works fine and the graphs gets updated but when the graph moves no additional datapoints where loaded.

Here a video which shows the problem:
(If I zoom out and in again after shifting, all datapoints are present but not if I shift zoomed in)

https://github.com/AbelHeinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair/assets/24574743/2eeee4a4-3244-4414-b026-97b870049254

I tried to find something in code of plugin, but I'm not a js developer and didn't understand it well.

Is there any way to call something like `chart.crosshair.update();` to tell the plugin or chart.js to reload the datapoints for the selected time range?

I tried to call `chart.crosshair.doZoom()` to trigger the zooming again but the function is not callable.

I also tried it with something like:

```
chart.options.scales.x.min = chart.options.scales.x.min -1000;
chart.options.scales.x.max = chart.options.scales.x.max -1000;
```

But this did not solve the problem.

**Some help or any hint would be great, thanks in advance!**

Comment: More code is needed so we can run and debug it. It might be a bug in chart.js (which makes this quite interesting and the solution would be to re-zoom) but it's also possible there's a bug in your code. For instance, the update code fragment seems slightly off. `element["x"]` appears to be a number since you subtract 1000 from it; but then what's `element["x"]["y"]`? - it should be `undefined`.  It probably doesn't amount to anything since you don't assign the result of `data.map`, so you could have just used `data.forEach` with just the first statement (the -1000 assignment).

Comment: Hi @kikon, my dataset elements are e.g  `{"x": 1700342072000, "y": 140}` where x is a timestamp in epoch and y are the watt value. The usage of `data.map` seems to work because the graph moves and only x is modified (reduced or increased by 1000 milliseconds), the data from y is untouched, because i don't want to change the wattage values. I tried also using the suggested forEach ```chart.data.datasets[0].data.forEach((element) => {

        element["x"] =  element["x"] - 1000
        return element["x"]["y"];
      });``` basically it works, the graphs moves but the problem is the same.

Comment: @kikon you can test it live here: https://fitcompare.astromic.de ..i uploaded also the javascript file. the function begins in line 1175: https://gist.github.com/NiTRoeSE/96eeb1d24296534249b11bfa1ec624d0  and you can find 2 example fit files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O2ZMBdW8ylFO5WIstK6vQM3pSCWkwr1H?usp=sharing  ... i hope that helps ?

Comment: Since the issue seems interesting, I decided to create myself a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ps6ycLn/) (zoom in by dragging then press shift left button) which shows that indeed the problem is the result of using `chartjs-plugin-crosshair`. We wouldn't have that problem if we used [`chartjs-plugin-zoom`](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/), see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhg78ao1/).

Comment: This is not a bug but a feature of the plugin; its implementation starts [here](https://github.com/AbelHeinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair/blob/master/src/trace.js#L383). The plugin is "filtering" the data after each zoom, removing invisible points. That is probably intended to enhance performance. It can however be undone in `afterZoom`, by restoring the original data from `chart.crosshair.originalData`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/951hfcxu/). One could imagine a method that would restore data points only when they are needed by the shift functions but that's a lot more complicated

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your effort. :) That's it, i can see it know. I implemented restoring of data in afterZoom Callback, exactly the same way you done it, it works so far like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/951hfcxu/) , but i loose the labels when i zoom in. i tried to reproduce this in fiddle but don't get it. In fiddle the labels are shown even the data is restored, with my code i loose it if i zoom in, the only difference is, i use chart.js 4+ and crosshair plugin in version [4.0.1](https://github.com/AbelHeinsbroek/chartjs-plugin-crosshair/tree/v4.0.1).That's a strange behavior.

Comment: Mhh i think i have only two choices, i try to implement the dynamic restoring of datapoints only if data shifts. Or i try to implement it with chartjs-plugin-zoom, drop crosshair and try to get synced pan zooming working. I tend to try opportunity one because with the filtered datasets with the crosshair plugin it's possible to calculate the average values for zoomed in ranges and that's a nice feature, maybe that's also possible with chartjs-plugin-zoom.

Comment: What exactly happens, which labels do you loose? Can you make that update in the online code? Chartjs4+ should be the same as the one I included in the fiddle, that is the latest. However, `chartjs-plugin-crosshair` v4.0.1 doesn't seem to have a release, I can't get it from neither cdn nor npm, they all have v2.0.0, how did you get it?

Comment: Hello,happy new year & sorry for the delay, i was in holiday. If i restore the data in afterZoom callback like in fiddle, i loose all tooltip labels if i hover datapoints when i have zoomed in, the tooltips are not shown. If i reset zoom than the tooltip labels are shown again till i zoom in again. ( No errors in console) I try to reproduce that in fiddle but had no luck till now. I also used crosshair 4.0.1 for testing this but this seems not the problem. BTW: I compiled version 4.0.1 crosshair plugin with gulp for myself from the 4.0.1 branch, there are no releases on cdn or npm.

Comment: After a painstaking debugging session I found out that the fact that tooltips don't work after zoom with `originalData` restored is related to the option  `animation: false`, though I don't fully understand the connection; here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n57rc1ou/) to reproduce that behaviour. The tooltips appear to work fine on zoom if one uses `animation: {duration: 0}` instead [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n57rc1ou/1/).

Comment: In an unrelated discovery I see that `interaction.mode: 'index'` doesn't work well when the chart is zoomed *and* shifted. With the current version on https://fitcompare.astromic.de/, after you zoom in and then shift one curve a significant amount, the two points for the tooltip are also shifted by the same amount - they have different x values. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F6Js.png).

Comment: 1000 thanks, that's great!
I would never have thought that it had anything to do with animation duration. I would say that saved this project. I am super grateful for your help. I also didn't understand the connection but i´m happy that it works this way. :)

Comment: Yes `interaction.mode: 'index'` doesn't work well  if shifted, i found out that 
`interaction: { mode: 'nearest', intersect: false,axis: 'x',}` works as excpected if you shift the graphs. A fixed version is live. Thanks again, really great help.